# Does Least square solution admits element of Sobolev space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization

I am working on determining an inverse problem of finding $x$ from $Ax=b$. Is it a valid a question to say that I want my solution to be an element of Sobolev space? If so how can I find an optimal (in some sense) solution which admits only element from Sobolev space? Is it true that least square solution does not limit solution from Sobolev space only? Is it true that Tikhonov regularization method would ensure solution from Sobolev space? If true how can it be proved (at least under suitable conditions)?

Comment: If $x$ and $b$ are functions in a sobolev space (they are function spaces!) and $A$ is a operator, why not?

Comment: @user251257 the problem is $b$ may not be an element of Sobolev space.

Comment: do you mean whether that the solution $x^*$ could be smoother than the specified domain of $A$? That is indeed possible.

Comment: @user251257 sorry, did not understand by "specified domain of  $A$"

Comment: You have defined $A$ on some space say $X=H^0=L^2$. Then, depending on your problem, the solution might be smoother say in $H^1$.

Comment: @user251257 I see. I am assuming Tikhonov regularization  does that is not it?

Comment: it is more the other way around. The regularization is only defined on smoother spaces. You hope that the regularized solution is also / converges to the solution on the rougher space.

Comment: @user251257 ok, you are correct. That was exactly I am looking for.

Comment: that is the basic idea of regularization. Usually $Ax=b$ doesn't have a solution or many solutions on the rougher space.